# displaying table data from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

here is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [4] => no
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => yes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 3
            [4] => yes
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 4
            [4] => no
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 5
            [4] => yes
        )

)
```

this is what i tried, i'm creating a tables tr portion and what it does is duplicate itself for each record that is being displayed. How else can this be written so that it displays correctly? I know it must be simple i just cant wrap my head around it.

```
<?php 

$units = json_decode($tablerow);
foreach($units as $unit) : for($i=0;$i<=count($unit)-1;$i++) : ?>

<tr class="rows">
    <td><input type='text' name='bedroom[]' value='<?=$unit[$i];?>' class='input-small'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='bath[]' value='<?=$unit[$i];?>' class='input-small'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='sqrt[]' value='<?=$unit[$i];?>' class='input-small'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='price[]' value='<?=$unit[$i];?>' class='input-small'></td>
    <td>
        <select name='avail[]' class='input-small'>
        <option value='yes' <?=($unit[$i] == 'yes') ? 'selected="selected' : '';?>>Yes</option>
        <option value='no' <?=($unit[$i] == 'no') ? 'selected="selected' : '';?>>No</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-small removeRow">remove</button></td>
</tr>
<?php endfor; endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You double-bubble the loopy-dupy.

Just take the foreach, remove the for inside. Drop `$i` and replace `$units` with `$unit`. See as well http://php.net/foreach.

Example:

```
$units = json_decode($tablerow);

foreach ($units as $unit) : ?>
<tr class="rows">
    <td><input type='text' name='bedroom[]' value='<?=$unit[0];?>' class='input-small'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='bath[]' value='<?=$unit[1];?>' class='input-small'></td>

...
```

There is a fixed (1:1) relationship between the sub-value (e.g. bedroom, bath) and the index in the `$unit`. You can hard-encode it (bedroom = 0, bath = 1, ...).

You could also provide a transposing from numeric indexes into named properties by wrapping into a decorating iterator creating each subtype on the the fly. This can also help you to turn `yes` and `no` into `true` and `false` for example. But if this is only one-time output, I'd say it's not yet worth.

An intermediate is to move initialization code to the top of the loop:

```
foreach ($units as $unit) {

    $unit[4] = $unit[4] === 'yes';
    $unit= array_map('intval', $unit); # escape all values to prevent injection
?>

...

    <td>
      <select name='avail[]' class='input-small'>
        <option value='yes' <?= $unit[4] ? 'selected="selected' : '';?>>Yes</option>
        <option value='no' <?= !$unit[4] ? 'selected="selected' : '';?>>No</option>
      </select>
    </td>

...

<? } ?>
```

Comment: nice thanks, my variable was $unit instead of units across i just might of copied an older version, good eye. And I love the "You double-bubble the loopy-dupy." LMAO. Thanks for your post

Comment: take care you don't allow HTML injection e.g. inside attribute value and inside tag values. That was totally missing in your example and you should always take care of that. And yeah, some fun :D

Comment: is double-bubble a name of a chewing gum? I was watching food-factory and saw this manufacturing of double-bubble. Yellow pink and blue wrapper right?

Comment: @hakre, yea of course, im using an mvc to add/display data and each input is cleaned. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the `for` loop, just refer each `$unit` array's element by its index:

```
foreach($units as $unit) :?>

<tr class="rows">
    <td><input type='text' name='bedroom[]' value='<?=$unit[0];?>' class='input-small'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='bath[]' value='<?=$unit[1];?>' class='input-small'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='sqrt[]' value='<?=$unit[2];?>' class='input-small'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='price[]' value='<?=$unit[3];?>' class='input-small'></td>
    <td>
        <select name='avail[]' class='input-small'>
        <option value='yes' <?=($unit[4] == 'yes') ? 'selected="selected' : '';?>>Yes</option>
        <option value='no' <?=($unit[4] == 'no') ? 'selected="selected' : '';?>>No</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-small removeRow">remove</button></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```